# Query from 3 different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In this query below, how do you do a query

where if tbl3.CID exists in tbl1.ID or tbl3.CID exists in tbl2.ID where alert <> '',

then 'CONFIRM' else 'OUT' end Result?

```
select * from tbl3, tbl4 where tbl3.type = tbl4.name and tgl4.GroupName <> 'abc'

tbl1 
ID Prime_Number
1  1-11
1  1-22
2  2-11

tbl2
ID Alert
1  NULL
2  NULL
3  XOM

tbl3
CID  Sales
1    100
3    200
4    300

tbl4
Name  GroupName
CORP  Corporates
INTL  International
```

Expected result

```
Result  CID  Sales
CONFIRM 1    100   --> from tbl1
CONFIRM 3    200   --> from tbl2
OUT     4    300
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: If you're selecting from `tbl3` and `tbl4`, why are you expecting results from `tbl1` and `tbl2`?

Answer (score 0):

`exists` comes to mind:

```
select t3.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from tbl1 t1 where t1.id = t3.cid)
             then 'CONFIRM'
             when exists (select 1 from tbl2 t2 where t2.id = t3.cid and t2.alert is not null)
             then 'CONFIRM'
             else 'OUT'
        end) as result
from table3 t3;
```